# How to construct a function which satisfies conditions below?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f_0，f_1，···$ be an enumeration of partial functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$. Construct a function $g$ from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ t such that $Dom(g)≠Dom(f_i)$ for each $i$.

I know  diagonal method is the key.  Maybe if $f_i$ is total, then $g$ is total. If $f_i$ is not total, then $dom(f_i)\subset dom(g)$ .

I would appreciate if you could give more details.

Comment: The presence of functions here seems to be an irrelevant distraction.  Writing $A_i=Dom(f_i)$, you just want to find some subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which is not equal to $A_i$ for any $i$.

Comment: @EricWofsey   Of course I need to find the subset.  But which subset?

Comment: Well, are you familiar with the fact that there are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I know the subset exists. Can you define the fuction?

Comment: @EricWofsey and I am not familiar with set theory.

Comment: Were the tags chosen by rolling a d12 die?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that you don't care what the function value is, just whether it is defined.  This is the point of Eric Wofsey's first comment.  Nothing in the problem talks about function values.  Each partial function has a domain, which is a subset of $\Bbb N$.  You are looking to make the domain of $g$ differ from the domains of all the $f_i$.  So $f_0$ is either defined on $0$ or not.....